# How do I texture paint with glow?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-painting, texture-baking, emission

I [found someone doing this](https://gyazo.com/b793d3357f8467dce1aca1a041a99192?token=e0f4e2305d8d2f7e23b9237e79fcdf2f) and I wondered how you do it in blender 2.8. Preferably in cycles as I need to texture bake the final result.

I'm willing to add more details if needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the painting per se.

First, you need to paint the emission map of your shader :
[image]

Make sure to use black as blank color when creating the texture, so it doesn't emit light when nothing is painted.
I don't use the Principled BSDF's emission here because there's no strength input.

The glow itself comes from his viewport which is in rendered mode:

[image]

And using Eevee which has a bloom effect that can be seen in the viewport:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/A2D2mJs.png]

You can do the same with Cycles, except it doesn't have any SFX visible in the viewport, you would need to do it through compositing using a glare node in fog glow mode:

[image]